# How to apply a fomula multiple times at different intervals to entire column? OO Calc

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc, cells

I am using Open Office Calc on windows 8.1 Pro

I have the following data already sorted nicely.

```
    A      B       C
--+-----------------------
1 | Bmw     Gold     £80
2 | Bmw     Silver   £60
3 | Bmw     Blue     £50
4 | Bmw     Green    £20
5 | Merc    Orange   £50
6 | Merc    Red      £10
7 | Ford    Green    £22
8 | Ford    Green    £55
9 | Ford    Blue     £80
10| Ford    Grey     £90
11| Ford    Black    £68
```

I would like to total each **Car Make** and put the result in a cell to the right like in the following example

```
      A      B       C        D       E
--+---------------------------------------------
1 | Bmw     Gold     £80    
2 | Bmw     Silver   £60
3 | Bmw     Blue     £50
4 | Bmw     Green    £20    Total    £210
5 | Merc    Orange   £50 
6 | Merc    Red      £10    Total    £60
7 | Ford    Green    £22
8 | Ford    Green    £55
9 | Ford    Blue     £80
10| Ford    Grey     £90
11| Ford    Black    £68    Total    £315
```

I can get the totals of each **Car Make** with formula `=SUMIF(C1:C11;"Bmw";A1:A11)`, and manually put this formula in a cell to the right of each **Car Make**, adjusting the formula and location everytime it differs.

However if I have 100 different Car Makes in 5000 Rows this would be a timely And error prone task(when selecting the Range's inside `SUMIF`).

Is there not a menu in Calc which I can apply some sort of formula which is worked out based on a range of data?
Or perhaps a better simple way to do it?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Column D put this formula in the first row:

```
=IF(A1<>A2;"Total";"")
```

Then in E1 put:

```
=IF(A1<>A2;SUMIF(A:A;A1;C:C);"")
```

And copy down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer would work if OO Calc allowed A:A, C:C shorthand for entire columns, but it does not, so I am working on a neat workaround as we speak